# What is the significance of blinking systems on the galaxy map?

Tags: mass-effect-3

When I'm viewing the Galaxy Map form the Normandy and selecting where to go with a mass relay, some of the systems appear to pulse or blink.

At first I thought this was to indicate mission locations, but some of them are blinking with no obvious missions to complete. It's clearly not the presence of the Reapers.

Why are some of the systems blinking?

Answer (score 4):

Blinking indicates that you currently have an active mission in your log to complete there.

If you see no obvious mission, scan around the system and you should find a war asset or fuel depot to recover.

Comment: Fairly sure this behavior is *intended*, but it doesn't work perfectly. I've had 100% systems with no active missions blink.

Comment: There's a bug that's been talked about fairly extensively on the BioWare forums. Specifically for a system in the lower right portion of the map.

Comment: I currently only have 3 active missions: Eden Prime: Resistance (because I missed a piece of information), Citadel: Cerberus cyphers and Priority: Horizon.  The Minos Wasteland is blinking for me though, where the wiki assures me I don't need to go for those.  Additionally, it's 100% searched.

Answer (score 1):

I have a system always blinking too, About 10 o'clock if the milky way were a clock, near the outside of the sector with the Citadel. called Minos Wasteland. For me it's currently at 100%, no missions. I went there anyway and found two systems, one called Fortis, the other Arrae, and both are 100% explored with no active missions in either. A glitch maybe? That seems to be the only one for me currently outside my only other active mission.

To add one more thing, if you pick up on conversations around the Citadel people ask you to find crap for them (or you eavesdrop about it...) Sometimes systems with the items they require will blink too. These won't be 100% explored, but I'm not sure if you can find the item before gaining the quest...

Comment: you can definitely find the item before getting the quest

Answer (score 0):

*It's just a glitch*.  With ME4 on the PS4, I went and got the trilogy for the PS3.  I have the Minos Wasteland system and the Citadel blinking all the time.  Checked everything a dozen or more times and have not found anything yet.  Might have something to do with the DLCs.  I did not have this problem until I got ashes and the weapons packs. (FYI: The Wpns pks are a waste of money.  For DLC they suck.)  Also, have a lot of reapers with no circles.  Working on getting 5000+ to save Shepard and these glitches have me stuck at 3400.  Read that on or offline does not matter for the 5000+, just in case anyone is curious.